# Hive: Couldn't understand the Statistics in EXAMPLE result

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm using Hive on MRv2. I prepared a table which contains billion tuples.
I wrote query like `EXPLAIN select count(*) from table`. The EXPLAIN result is below:

```
1> STAGE DEPENDENCIES:   Stage-1 is a root stage   Stage-0 depends on
2> stages: Stage-1
3> 
4> STAGE PLANS:   Stage: Stage-1
5>     Map Reduce
6>       Map Operator Tree:
7>           TableScan
8>             alias: table
9>             Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 39328468992 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
10>             Select Operator
11>               Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 39328468992 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
13>               Group By Operator
14>                 aggregations: count()
15>                 mode: hash
16>                 outputColumnNames: _col0
17>                 Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
18>                 Reduce Output Operator
19>                   sort order: 
20>                   Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
21>                   value expressions: _col0 (type: bigint)
22>       Reduce Operator Tree:
23>         Group By Operator
24>           aggregations: count(VALUE._col0)
25>           mode: mergepartial
26>           outputColumnNames: _col0
27>           Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
28>           File Output Operator
29>             compressed: false
30>             Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
31>             table:
32>                 input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
33>                 output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
34>                 serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
35> 
36>   Stage: Stage-0
37>     Fetch Operator
38>       limit: -1
39>       Processor Tree:
40>         ListSink
```

In the Statistics in line 9, although this table has billion tuples, the `Num rows` is 1.

Please teach me how the Statistics result in EXPLAIN is calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the external table.Since Hive is not aware of the metadata, it showed one row.

**Ex:**

```
Map Operator Tree:
      TableScan
        alias: test_ext_tb
        Statistics: **Num rows: 1 Data size: 452001824** Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
        Select Operator
          Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 452001824 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: COMPLETE
          Group By Operator
            aggregations: count()
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Do you mean the Statistic result represents output information?

Comment: @tbt Hey sorry my bad , you are right statistics should show the no of rows in the table. Since data size is big and it show only 1 row. I would suspect that this table might be an external table or some other format which "hive explain" could not able to read statistics , hence it might have showed 1 row.

Comment: Yes it should be the case. I just tested with external table and edited the answer.

Comment: @tbt did it answer your question ?

Comment: I'm sorry to reply late. I'm using an external table, so your thought is correct. Thanks.